# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Entity 'copy' not defined Magento

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap, wsdl

I try to use magento webservice but whene i try to call the webservice  :

$proxy = new SoapClient('http://mydomain.com/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

I get this error  :   Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://mydomain.com/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl' : Entity 'copy' not defined\n in /var/www/trunk/test.php:3\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/trunk/test.php(3),

So this Entity 'copy' not defined can you tell me why this exactly , should i add something in my server ?

```
 $proxy = new SoapClient('http://127.0.0.1/magento/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl=1');

// create authorized session id using api user name and api key
// $sessionId = $proxy->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('karimeri', 'xxxxxxx');

 // Get customer info for customer id = 1
$customerinfo = $proxy->customerCustomerInfo($sessionId,1);

print_r($customerinfo);
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: of cours , this is my code  :

Comment: That didn't come through.  Try using http://pastebin.com/

Comment: sorry i dindn't understand you ?

Comment: plz help to solve this , really i'm blocked

Comment: Can you post `test.php`?

Comment: i have added the test.php to my post  plz see it and tell me what wrong plz  ?

Comment: any help  plz , really i'm blocked

Comment: I guess the problem is in the WSDL used. It might contain the entity `&copy;` which is not defined in XML, but in HTML, so the XML parser chokes on that. Examine the WSDL file and validate it.

Comment: the probleme was in my url call i , i had to add www to my url call i mean : instead exemple.com/api/soap?wsdl i had to write exemple.com/api/soap?wsdl :), thanks brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a host entry for mydomain.com that points to your 127.0.0.1 address? Can you actually see the wsdl in your browser if you visit the URL manually? Do you have all the PHP libraries installed like simplexml? If you install something like Charles web proxy and run the request it might yield more info as to what is happening like possible redirects and responses. Do you have the log enabled and is there any error in the magento system or exception log?

Need a bit more info to help really. Also is the real error message relating to mydomain.com or does it actually say 127.0.0.1? If so, have you configured the site base URL's in the admin? I suspect it may be a DNS issue at this moment.

Comment: Yes the probleme DNS , i had to add www to my url call i mean :  instead http://exemple.com/api/soap?wsdl  i had to write http://www.exemple.com/api/soap?wsdl  :), thanks brother.